# PHP: exclude a word

Tags: php, time, internationalization

I would like to exclude the word "*mois*" from the code below to prevent the addition of an 's' to it.

```
function ago($time) {
   $periods = array("seconde", "minute", "heure", "jour", "semaine", "mois", "année", "décade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

   $now = time();

       $difference     = $now - $time;
       $tense         = "ago";

   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
       $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   }

   $difference = round($difference);

   if($difference != 1) {
       $periods[$j].= "s";
   }

   return "Il y a $difference $periods[$j].";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `substr($periods[$j], -1)` you get the last character from a string, thus

```
if($difference != 1 && substr($periods[$j], -1) != 's') {
    $periods[$j].= "s";
}
```